# A word to describe a person who attempts to not care about other's opinions

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that describes someone who tries to not care about other people's opinions and attempts on being free-spirited (however, being totally care-free about others' opinions is impossible, so I want to know a word that describes the attempt of being free-spirited).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the best phrase for this is *blissfully ignorant*.

It means you're ignorant of something, such as other people's opinions, and because of that you are happy/uncaring in a lighthearted way.

Comment: Ignorant would mean unaware. So he cannot try not to care about others opinions as he is blissfully ignorant.

Comment: Ignorant doesn't necessarily mean unaware. Ignorant means you are ignoring something. That can either be willingly or unwillingly. If you are trying to not care about someone's opinion of you, you're being ignorant.

Comment: ya that's about what I was trying to think of, thx!

Comment: ignorant means lacking knowledge or awareness in general; uneducated or unsophisticated.It does not mean the word "ignore"

Answer (score 1):

**INSOUCIANT**

Google's definition:

in·sou·ci·ant 
inˈso͞osēənt, 
adjective

showing a casual lack of concern; indifferent.

"an insouciant shrug"

synonyms:   nonchalant, untroubled, unworried, unruffled, unconcerned, indifferent, blasé, heedless, careless;

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some of these are what you're looking for:

> **Uncaring**: not displaying sympathy or concern for others.
>
> **Cavalier**: showing a lack of proper concern.
>
> **Asocial**: inconsiderate of or hostile to others.
>
> **Apathetic**: showing or feeling no interest.
>
> **Stoic**: of or relating to the school of philosophy founded by Zeno, who
>   taught that people should be free from passion, unmoved by joy or
>   grief, and submit without complaint to unavoidable necessity.
>
> **Egoist**: a person who is preoccupied with his own interests.

Answer (score 0):

"egocentric"  might express the meaning you are looking for I guess